# How to solve mysqli.so, cannot open shared object file

Tags: command-line, server, apache2, php

```
Message:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/extension/mysqli.so' (tried: /path/to/extension/mysqli.so (/path/to/extension/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718//path/to/extension/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718//path/to/extension/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))</p>


<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Core Warning</p>
<p>Message:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/path/to/extension/mysqli.so' (tried: /path/to/extension/mysqli.so (/path/to/extension/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718//path/to/extension/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718//path/to/extension/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))</p>
<p>Filename: Unknown</p>
<p>Line Number: 0</p>
```

`find / -name 'mysqli.so'`

```
/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so
/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so
/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysqli.so
```

`find / -name 'php.ini'`

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to reinstall [the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=mysqli.so) for this library depending on your Ubuntu version:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.0-mysql # for 16.04 LTS
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.2-mysql # for 18.04 LTS
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.4-mysql # for 20.04 LTS and 20.10
```